# START_ID and END_ID in same field from diferent nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to import data using neo4j import tools and I need to create a relationship betwen two differents nodes in differents csv with differents labels, one complement other and I need them separated.
The only key i own to use on START_ID and END_ID is the primary key of node which is the same for both.

Basically, what i need in cypher is this:

```
MATCH (n:LABEL1), (m:LABEL2) 
WHERE n.key = m.key
MERGE (n)-[r:complement]->(m)
```

But I realy need to do this on import tool from csv. How to do that?

Comment: If you are talking about the [neo4j-admin import](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/) command, have you read the documentation?

Comment: Yes, is about `neo4j-admin import`.
I try to read the documentation, but don't find something like this. Maybe is because my english fluency not is so good, but i really try.
I find how to create relationships in the documentation, but this case is most specific because I have only one field with IDs, not two as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience working with LOAD CSV, the functions that load data can only read what's in the CSV or in the graph. I've used three options to solve this type of problem.

1. Load all the data from both CSVs with the key as a property, then run a query like the one you used in your question (which adds the relationships between the nodes).
2. Create a third CSV that explicitly lists the relationships between the nodes and use that as a third upload batch. IE: you'd load both CSVs with the nodes, then use the third CSV to add the relationships.
3. You can alter your CSVs so that all the nodes are in the same document - IE have a START_ID and END_ID column. This option only works when the nodes only have one property (the unique identifier).